# how can i get the width of an element that's populated dynamically with jquery

Tags: jquery

How can I get the width of the .box div (it is populated dynamically) with jQuery to make it scroll-able horizontally within its wrapper (.box_wrpr) if .box gets wider then .box_wrpr or if more .box's are added dynamically.

**HTML**

```
<div class="box_wrpr" style="overflow-x: auto; overflow-y: hidden; height: 285px;">
    <div class="box">
        <header class="box_header">
                <h3><span class="gray">Box</span> 1</h3>

            <p class="box_price">$0000.00</p>
        </header>
        <div class="box_images">
            <div class="IMG">   <span class=""></span>

                <img class="image_box" src="#" alt="">
                <p class="item_count">item <span class="count_number">1</span>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="bottom_p">
            <p class="info"><span class="_icon"></span>Home - <span class="Mode">Standard</span>
            </p>
            <p class="date">01/21/14</p>
            <p class="ship"><span class="arrived_icon"></span>Est. Date - 01/28/14</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div.box {
    height: 235px;
    min-width: 175px;
    border: 2px solid #47baa4;
    float: left;
    margin: 5px;
    background: #eff6f6;
    top: 25px;
}
.box_wrpr {
    height: 285px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Breaking that very long sentence into smaller ones might make your question clearer.

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/width/ or one of the other width measurements that jQuery provides should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this is how you get the width.

```
$('.box').width();
```

But if I understand correctly, you might not need it's width at all. You just need to specify a fixed width for the wrapper, and set the boxes overflwo to scrollable.

http://jsfiddle.net/X64yw/1/

If you want to add more boxes, create a div for the boxes within the wrapper and make the overflow scrollable there.

Comment: The content of the .box is generated dynamyclly, so I cant set a width for it.

Comment: You don't have to set the width of the box/es, but the width of the container. And you will also need to add overflow-y: scroll.

Comment: Doesn't work! because the .box div's are floated left so they don't have a width, so they never overflow!!! that's why i want to get the width if each .box once the page has loaded and add the width to each .box with jquery .css

Comment: Something like this maybe? 

$(document).ready( function() { 
    $('.box').css('width', function() {
        return $(this).width();
    });
});

But I am not sure if it will work...

Answer (score 0):

Odd question... Loukas Avramidis pointed out very well how to simply obtain the width of a box. If you wanted to modify the overflow-x or overflow-y of the div.box_wrpr element, you could do something like this in a function, and call it whenever you dynamically change .box sizes or the number of .box elements:

```
var boxWrapperWidth = $('div.box_wrpr').width();
var boxWrapperHeight = $('div.box_wrpr').height();
var totalBoxWidth = 0;
var totalBoxHeight = 0;

$('div.box').each(function(){
     totalBoxWidth += $(this).width();
     totalBoxHeight += $(this).height();
});

if(totalBoxWidth > boxWrapperWidth){
     $('div.box_wrpr').css('overflow-x','scroll');
}
else{
     $('div.box_wrpr').css('overflow-x','hidden');
}

if(totalBoxHeight > boxWrapperHeight){
     $('div.box_wrpr').css('overflow-y','scroll');
}
else{
     $('div.box_wrpr').css('overflow-y','hidden');
}
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that I need it to scroll horizontally not vertically.